# How should we show following ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I am facing a interrogation, and I hope you could help me to find an answer.

I am selecting X items in a row. 
I have already made a custom alert for 1 item selection in a row that look like this.

[image]

Here is how I call the alert

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let myAlert = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "uploadAlert") as! AlertUploadViewController
myAlert.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
myAlert.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve

let image = self.interventionsSelected[0].picture
myAlert.initAlert(image: image!)

request.view.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

As you can see, I'm only taking the first image selected. Now, I want to take ALL selected images.

My problematic here is that I want to link all alerts and make smooth transition between them. How can I link the dismissing of an alert and the presenting of the next one ?

- Should I make a array of all alerts and catch the dismissing ?
- Should I have to use closure and linking all closure ?

I am not sure how I can do that in the best possible smooth way.

Comment: The option of making 1 alert for multiple pictures is acceptable?

Comment: if i select 50 images, then there will be 50 alert to show? i think thats not good experience for user. i suggest one upload alert can contains multiple images.

Comment: No I can't group images, they HAVE to be separate for every clients. 

The user will not have to select like 50 pictures, so this is not a problem, the maximum will be 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to maintain a delegate method for the alertcontroller of yours

make a Protocol as

```
protocol AlertProtocol: class {
    func showNextAlert()
}
```

now assign your main view controller as its delegate

in your alertviewcotntroller:

```
var delegate: AlertProtocol?
```

and as you click button in alert controller to do something and close the alert , in its completion handler

```
self.dismiss(animated: true) {
        self.delegate.showNextAlert()
    }
```

this was your current alert closes, and a window heirarcy is maintained and another alert is opened with new data in flow

Comment: It worked perfectly with hero transition, very smooth and easy to implement, thanks ! :)

Comment: @Sacha.R always happy to be helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

I would not go with multiple alerts at the same time because it seems visually what will happen is your darker background will be even darker with more alerts. And when dismissing each of them you will have the background brighter...

Supporting multiple images internally seems quite good but it is maybe not scalable if you later choose that some of these internal views will be completely different (one for images the other for whatever you can think of).

The best scenario I can think of is creating this overlay view controller with a container view. So this view is capable of showing view controllers and is able to animate them internally. The interface from how you then use it would look something like:

```
let container = MyContainerViewController.instantiateFromStoryboard()
container.injectViewControllers([
    ShowImageViewController.instantiateFromStoryboard(image: image[0], delegate: self),
    ShowImageViewController.instantiateFromStoryboard(image: image[1], delegate: self),
    ShowSomethingElseViewController.instantiateFromStoryboard(data: data[0], delegate: self)
])
present(container...
```

So then I guess you would have a delegate method such as

```
func embeddedController(_ sender: UIViewController, shouldProceedWithData outputData: Any?) {
    if container.canGoForward() {
        container.forward(animated: true)
    } else {
        container.dismiss(...
    }
}
```